# Protocolo TLS 1.2 CT-e 3.0 e NF-e 4.0

Tags: c#, ssl, tls

Estou desenvolvendo a CT-e 3.0 e a NF-e 4.0, nas mesmas cita a necessidade em mudar o protocolo de segurança de SSL para TLS 1.2 com o prazo de 02/04/2018.

Nos webservice de recepção não tem informações sobre os protocolos, a documentação de ambos (CT-e e NF-e), deixa um pouco vago as alterações que são necessárias.

a aplicação é desenvolvida em c# e VB.NET.

Devido a isso, busquei implementações na internet chegando a seguinte implementação: `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 Or SecurityProtocolType.Ssl`

Mesmo implementando isso não tivemos diferenças e também não conseguimos executar o teste para saber se é somente está alteração que deve ser feita ou se a alteração também deve ser feita em certificado digital e/ou cadeia de certificados.

Gostaríamos de ter certeza que são somente estas as alterações necessárias?

Caso tiver algo a mais a ser implementado gostaria da contribuição da comunidade.

OBS: Utilizamos Certificado A1 e A3.

Comment: Acredito que seja só isso mesmo, mas por acaso você chegou a alguma conclusão diferente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiz o seguinte teste:

Usei um aplicativo para consultar status da SEFAZ MG no ambiente de homologação com .NET Framework 2.0, sem alterar o protocolo para TLS 1.2.

Abri o Wireshark e ativei um filtro de pacotes para protocolo TLS 1.2 desta forma:

```
ssl.record.version == 0x0303
```

O resultado foi que nenhum pacote foi exibido, ou seja, não transmitiu com o protocol TLS 1.2.

A seguir, alterei o código para usar o TLS 1.2. No .NET 2.0, não tem a constante na enumeração, mas é possível fazer o equivalente da seguinte forma:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

Ao executar o aplicativo com esta alteração, o Wireshark exibiu pacotes conta um IP da SEFAZ com o protocolo TLS 1.2.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Conclusão: Esta é a única alteração necessária.